# чат на сокетах джава многопоточность исключение NPE

Tags: java, многопоточность, сокет

Есть приложение на JavaFX (простой чат на сокетах).
Когда клиент отправляет сообщение, Сервер получает его и отправляет другому клиенту(второму). Второй клиент принимает сообщение и может вывести его на консоль но когда я хочу вывести его на TextArea выходит такая ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at whatsapp.web.HomePageController$Listener.run(HomePageController.java:45)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

А вот и та 45-я строка (homeChatHistoryArea это мой TextArea)

```
private class Listener implements Runnable { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String msg;
        try{
            while((msg = reader.readLine()) != null){
                homeChatHistoryArea.appendText(msg+"\n"); // 45-я строка
            }
        } catch (IOException ex){ex.getMessage();}
    }
}
```

но если я делаю так то сообщение успешно выводится на консоль

```
private class Listener implements Runnable { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String msg;
        try{
            while((msg = reader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(msg+"\n"); // 45-я строка
            }
        } catch (IOException ex){ex.getMessage();}
    }
}
```

А это весь код так на всякий случай, после авторизации пользователя запускается метод startApp

```
package whatsapp.web;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class HomePageController {

private final String IP = "localhost";
private final int PORT = 5859;
private static BufferedReader reader;
private static PrintWriter writer;

@FXML private TextArea homeChatHistoryArea;
@FXML private TextField homeMessageInput;

protected void startApp() {
    setNet();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Listener());
    thread.start();
}

@FXML
private void sendMessage() {
    String message = homeMessageInput.getText();
    homeChatHistoryArea.appendText(message + "\n");
    homeMessageInput.clear();
    writer.println(message);
writer.flush();
}


private class Listener implements Runnable { 
@Override
public void run() {
        String msg;
        try{
    while((msg = reader.readLine()) != null){
                homeChatHistoryArea.appendText(msg+"\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex){ex.getMessage();}
}
}

private void setNet() {
    try {
        Socket sock = new Socket(IP, PORT);
        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
        reader = new BufferedReader(is);
        writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException ex){System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}      
}
}
```

А это сервер
        package whatsapp.web;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WhatsAppServer {

private static ArrayList<PrintWriter> streams;
private static final int PORT = 5859;

private static void startServer() {
streams = new ArrayList<>();
try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        while (true) {
            Socket sock = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Got user!");
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            streams.add(writer);
            Thread t = new Thread(new Listener(sock));
            t.start();
        }
} catch (IOException ex) {System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}
}

private static class Listener implements Runnable { 
BufferedReader reader;
Listener(Socket sock) {
        try {
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
    reader = new BufferedReader(is);
        } catch (IOException ex) {System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}
}

@Override
public void run() {
        String msg;
        try {
    while ((msg = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(msg);
                tellEveryone(msg);
    }
        } catch (IOException ex) {System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}
}
}

private static void tellEveryone(String msg){
    java.util.Iterator<PrintWriter> it = streams.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
        try {
    PrintWriter writer = it.next();
    writer.println(msg);
    writer.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) {System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
startServer();
}

}
```

Comment: добавьте **fxml** в вопрос.

Comment: все разобрался спасибо,
я сначала запустил поток ,а потом только инициализировал TextArea, 
исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас переменная `homeChatHistoryArea` в этой строчке содержит `null`. Проверьте, что у вас правильно названа переменная и у поля в **fxml** правильный идентификатор.